# Trying to style a select element by referencing the name attribute?

Tags: html, forms

I'm trying to style a drop down menu and unfortunately it doesn't have a class applied to it. However, it has got a name attribute. So, can the dropdown be styled by referencing the name attribute?

```
<select name="ym_birthdate_month">
   <option value="" selected="selected">Month</option>
   <option value="01">January</option>
   <option value="02">February</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, attribute selectors are part of the [CSS2 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#attribute-selectors).

```
select[name=ym_birthday_month] {
  // insert CSS here
}
```

That will match anything with a name attribute of "ym_birthday_month". If you need it to be case sensitive (which I don't think you do based on your example):

```
select[name="ym_birthday_month"] {
    // insert CSS here
}
```